# Display array values as unique tooltip in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts, tooltip

I am trying to display values of an array as tooltip in highcharts line graph.I am currently using values entered from a textbox as tooltip but trying to display array values as tooltip..the js fiddle is given here http://jsfiddle.net/RbenU/75/

the tooltip code i am using is..

```
       tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var serieI = this.series.index;
            var index = categories.indexOf(this.x);
            var comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
            return '-->'+comment;
        }
    },
```

I want to display values of array n as tool-tip i.e. n[0] element for JAN, n[1] element for Feb so on and so forth..Points falling under the same month will have same tooltip..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the index you are getting from the categories array to get that value from n:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var index = categories.indexOf(this.x);
        return n[index];
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

declare an array:

```
 var myComments=["First input","second comment","another comment","last comment"];
```

instead of the line:

```
 var comment = $("input:eq(" + (index) + ")").val();
```

write the line:

```
 var comment = myComments[index];
```

and it should work...

**jsfiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yoav_barnea/2meEg/