# Highcharts Alternate unique name using tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I'm trying to build a highchart that when you hover over a scatter point you will get a separate unique id for the point.  I dug around for this information in the forums for a while and can't find it. 
I found this: [Display array values as unique tooltip in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019897/display-array-values-as-unique-tooltip-in-highcharts) but it's a category based reference.  I want each point to have it's own id.

So my data is as follows:

```
Sample ID       Y
Samp1   115.90  179.00
Samp2   37.50   188.00
Samp3   27.80   64.00
Samp4   51.90   228.00
Samp5   27.20   863.00
Samp6   478.80  575.00
Samp7   39.10   598.00
Samp8   22.80   244.00
```

I want the tooltip to display the series name, sample and the values of x and y for each point.
This helps me identify a point easily by not having to look it up by the x and y values.  So for each point I want the tooltip to report the sampleID (which would be samp1, 2, etc)

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/776yN/

Comment: Why not put the sample column directly in the data? Like: {x:21.8,y:222,samp:'samp4'}, then use the samp value in the tooltip?

Comment: Here's a simple example of what I'm saying: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/776yN/1/

Answer (score 0):

I advice to parse your data (in preprocessing) to avoid using array (for single point) like [10,10] but use object

```
{
  x: 10,
  y: 10
  id: 'sample12'
}
```

Then you will have access to custom parameter by `this.point.options.id` in tooltip parameter